# Py4JJavaError when writing Pyspark DataFrame to Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm trying to write a PySpark dataframe to a parquet file for a later stage in the project.
However when I try the code

```
final_basetable.write.parquet(path)
```

I get this error

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-afce49eef81b> in <module>
----> 1 final_basetable.write.parquet('/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/Final_Basetable_Parquet')

~/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in parquet(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)
   1248             self.partitionBy(partitionBy)
   1249         self._set_opts(compression=compression)
-> 1250         self._jwrite.parquet(path)
   1251 
   1252     def text(self, path, compression=None, lineSep=None):

~/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

~/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o405.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:874)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 28.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 28.0 (TID 1235) (192.168.0.196 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 604, in main
    process()
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 596, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 211, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 132, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 200, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in mapper
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in <genexpr>
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 77, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: g(f(*a))
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 77, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: g(f(*a))
  File "<ipython-input-24-db2455f1237f>", line 4, in translate_text
  File "/Users/feliw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/deep_translator/google_trans.py", line 120, in translate
    raise TooManyRequests()
deep_translator.exceptions.TooManyRequests: Server Error: You made too many requests to the server. According to google, you are allowed to make 5 requests per second and up to 200k requests per day. You can wait and try again later or you can try the translate_batch function

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.processInputs(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.<init>(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2$adapted(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:200)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 604, in main
    process()
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 596, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 211, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 132, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 200, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in mapper
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in <genexpr>
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 77, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: g(f(*a))
  File "/Users/feliw/Documents/1e Master + Masterproef/Big Data/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 77, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: g(f(*a))
  File "<ipython-input-24-db2455f1237f>", line 4, in translate_text
  File "/Users/feliw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/deep_translator/google_trans.py", line 120, in translate
    raise TooManyRequests()
deep_translator.exceptions.TooManyRequests: Server Error: You made too many requests to the server. According to google, you are allowed to make 5 requests per second and up to 200k requests per day. You can wait and try again later or you can try the translate_batch function

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.processInputs(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.<init>(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2$adapted(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    ... 1 more
```

We have used a translator tool that I suspect is the culprit of the problem were facing at this moment.
Does someone with more skill than me know the solution to this?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You have the python traceback of the error in this log:

```
deep_translator.exceptions.TooManyRequests: Server Error: You made too many requests to the server. According to google, you are allowed to make 5 requests per second and up to 200k requests per day. You can wait and try again later or you can try the translate_batch function
```

Seems like you are using the python library `deep-translator` with Google translation. So, you are subject to Google Translate quotas.

There is little you can do at Spark side. You can try to reduce the number of call to the Google Translate API, by concatenating the text in a pandas UDF for example.
Or you can try to use an other translate service with `deep-translator`, one that has less quotas restrictions.
An other solution is to move the translate part before or after the Spark script, so that you can introduce a delay between API calls.